# Windows 10 1703 - Direct Show and Media Foundation camera issue

Tags: winapi, directshow, ms-media-foundation

We are seeing a strange issue on both DirectShow and MediaFoundation where the camera is giving black frames. 
On running MFTrace on both the apps, we see that 
CMemInputPinDetours::Receive is not getting called (when comparing with working scenario). On what cases & scenarios this can happen?
Problem is seen only with Lenova laptops and only with Windows 10 1703 (i.e. creators update) on wards. Complete log of DirectShow app:
Also the Microsoft samples MFCaptureD3D and SimpleCapture doesn't work!
Not sure what we are missing here, can someone help?

Part of MFTrace log is listed at below:

> 1252,D2C 14:16:36.74678 CGraphHelpers::Trace @000002CB48084CA0 >>>>>>>>>>>>> Run graph
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74679 CGraphBuilderDetours::EnumFilters @000002CB48084CA0 - enter
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74680 CGraphBuilderDetours::EnumFilters @000002CB48084CA0 - exit
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74681 CGraphHelpers::TraceFilter @ Filter @000002CB60D7BCF8, name 'SinkFilter', vendor '(null)'
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74684 CGraphHelpers::TracePin @ Input pin @000002CB6602BDD8 (IMemInputPin @000002CB6602BE98) name 'VideoCapture', connected to filter @000002CB48091158 pin @000002CB480C9228, MT: majortype=MEDIATYPE_Video;subtype=MFVideoFormat_YUY2;bFixedSizeSamples=1;bTemporalCompression=0;lSampleSize=1843200;formattype=FORMAT_VideoInfo;pUnk=@0000000000000000;cbFormat=88
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74684 CGraphHelpers::TraceFilter @ Filter @000002CB48091158, name 'VideoCaptureFilter', vendor '(null)'
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74686 CGraphHelpers::TracePin @ Output pin @000002CB480C9228 name 'Capture', connected to filter @000002CB60D7BCF8 pin @000002CB6602BDD8, MT: majortype=MEDIATYPE_Video;subtype=MFVideoFormat_YUY2;bFixedSizeSamples=1;bTemporalCompression=0;lSampleSize=1843200;formattype=FORMAT_VideoInfo;pUnk=@0000000000000000;cbFormat=88
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74687 CGraphHelpers::TracePin @ Input pin @000002CB48084A18 (IMemInputPin @000002CB48084AD8) name 'Video Camera Terminal', NOT CONNECTED(!!!)
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74687 CGraphHelpers::TracePin @ Output pin @000002CB480845F8 name 'Still', NOT CONNECTED(!!!)
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74687 CGraphHelpers::Trace @000002CB48084CA0 <<<<<<<<<<<<< Run graph
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74687 CGraphBuilderDetours::EnumFilters @000002CB48084CA0 - enter
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74688 CGraphBuilderDetours::EnumFilters @000002CB48084CA0 - exit
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74688 CMemInputPinDetours::Attach @00007FF80B790928 - enter
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74688 CInterfaceDetours::AttachVtbl @00007FF80B790928 - enter
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74688 CDetourHelpers::AttachInterface @ - enter
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74691 CDetourHelpers::AttachInterface @ - exit
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74691 CInterfaceDetours::AttachVtbl @00007FF80B790928 - exit
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74691 CMemInputPinDetours::Attach @00007FF80B790928 - exit
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74691 CMemInputPinDetours::Attach @00007FF8129B7D10 - enter
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74691 CInterfaceDetours::AttachVtbl @00007FF8129B7D10 - enter
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74692 CDetourHelpers::AttachInterface @ - enter
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74693 CDetourHelpers::AttachInterface @ - exit
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74693 CInterfaceDetours::AttachVtbl @00007FF8129B7D10 - exit
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74693 CMemInputPinDetours::Attach @00007FF8129B7D10 - exit
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74696 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ - enter
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74811 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ Created {E436EBB1-524F-11CE-9F53-0020AF0BA770} System Clock (C:\Windows\System32\quartz.dll) @000002CB4805CE68 - traced interfaces: 
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74811 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ - exit
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74822 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ - enter
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74865 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ Created {877E4351-6FEA-11D0-B863-00AA00A216A1} Plug In Distributor: IKsClock (C:\Windows\System32\ksproxy.ax) @000002CB48090920 - traced interfaces: 
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.74865 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ - exit
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.78381 CMediaControlDetours::Run @000002CB480C98E8 - exit
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.78382 CMediaControlDetours::GetState @000002CB480C98E8 - enter
>   1252,D2C 14:16:36.78383 CMediaControlDetours::GetState @000002CB480C98E8 - exit
>   1252,1E08 14:16:54.49906 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ - enter
>   1252,1E08 14:16:54.49921 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ Created {9FC8E510-A27C-4B3B-B9A3-BF65F00256A8}  (C:\WINDOWS\system32\dataexchange.dll) @000002CB4805BD40 - traced interfaces: 
>   1252,1E08 14:16:54.49921 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ - exit
>   1252,D2C 14:16:54.57840 CMediaControlDetours::Pause @000002CB480C98E8 - enter
>   1252,D2C 14:16:54.58279 CMediaControlDetours::Pause @000002CB480C98E8 - exit
>   1252,D2C 14:16:54.58280 CMediaControlDetours::Stop @000002CB480C98E8 - enter
>   1252,D2C 14:16:54.79315 CMediaControlDetours::Stop @000002CB480C98E8 - exit

Comment: Please don't link to off-site resources for information that is vital to the question. You should probably take the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: @venki.thiyag it could be a driver problem. You can try updating the web camera driver.

Comment: Thanks @VuVirt for the reply. After updating to latest driver issue was still present. Wanted to know if any kind of security mechanism is causing this or any other issue with Graph or Topology setup.

Comment: @venki.thiyag I'm not aware of any security issues with the web cameras, but you can check the Lenovo software installed and also the antivirus software installed. Also see these: https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/a-trick-to-fix-lenovo-easy-camera-windows-10-driver-issues-for-y470-y570-y471a-y470p/; https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/windows-10/solved-lenovo-built-in-webcam-camera-not-working-windows-10/; https://support.lenovo.com/bg/en/solutions/ht503655

Comment: The question needs improvement and hence does not receive proper attention. It might be indeed a driver issue. You need to identify whether the camera works in GraphEdit, AMCap, with different media types, do you have black frames because you have no frames, or frames are coming and displayed as black, with blackness in data, or with data incorrectly marked up etc. Also does it help to turn off frame server or not. You do have things to try and MF log is not really informative.

Comment: Today got access to machine where the problem was seen, tried GraphEdit, AMCap both of them resulted in **failed HrStatus=80070005 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED** error. Topoedit from Windows 10 SDK and camera access in Chrome worked! but MFCaptureD3D and SimpleCapture sample applications failed. Not sure what exactly I am missing here, this issue started happening only after updating to Windows 10 1703 version onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause, Kaspersky antivirus was causing this problem, adding our application to trusted list solved the problem!

We see that Kaspersky 10 was being used on the machine, following the steps mentioned in the below link solved the problem:
https://support.kaspersky.com/9398#block2

In case if there is Kaspersky 2015, then below link can be used to solve the problem:
https://support.kaspersky.com/11157#block1